# class redeclaration in with factory pattern implementation

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm still fairly new to OOP and Patterns. I'm trying to make a module system (Module_A, Module_B, etc..), to call and decide which module needs to be instantiated I'm trying to implement a factory pattern. The problem that I'just started to get is that my script complains about the redeclaration of the parent class that all these modules share.

This is what the call to the factory looks like:

```
<?php echo ModuleFactory::build('Module_'.$layout); ?>
```

in this case `$layout` would be **Alpha**

and this is the factory class:

```
class ModuleFactory {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public static function build($type, $config = Array()) {
        require('Module.class.php');
        require($type.'.class.php');
        $module = new $type($config);

        return $module->build_module();
    }
}
```

and every `Module_X` class extends the `Module` class. I'm not sure if this implementation is good, but I would love to hear any alternatives.

Comment: put the `require('Module.class.php')` outside of the `build` method, maybe in the constructor

Comment: Use `require_once` instead of `require`. The file will only be included the first time you call it then preventing redeclaring. Alternatively you can implement a php [autoload function](http://www.php.net/autoload) which is called on class instantiation to include classes if they don't exist.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn that did it, dumb mistake. Any comments on the implementation?

Comment: Most probably `Module_Alpha.class.php` has a `require "Module.class.php"` and that's why it's being required twice beause you have a separate `require('Module.class.php');` before.

Comment: Before even starting OOP, you need to have the classes you need available to you. This starts, in PHP, with PSR and **autoloading**. You should not be dynamically including files in a class.